# Dimension of the span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So i have this question :

***The number of columns of a matrix gives the dimension of the span of the column vectors.***

I know that the answer is indeed FALSE.

But i want to back my answer up with a simple, right, yet CONCRETE explanation of why that is so.

I was thinking : the question if false due to the fact that the dimension o of the span of the column vectors is given by the maximum amount of linearly independent vectors.

is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, for instance you can just make all the columns scalar multiples of the first.  Or, even worse, consider the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take then null $n\times n$ matrix. It has $n$ columns, but the dimension of the span of the column vectors is $0$.

Comment: Hi carlos. I see you've really helped me a lot these past few days, and as, due to my insecurities ,i have asked a lot of questions on this website, i got question blocked. So i was willing to ask you , as i have , tommorrow, my most important exam , which is indeed maths, if you could genuinely help me with my last question , if i post it here as an image ? it would be so useful , seriously . thanks if you do

Comment: @MichaelMorello Do a Google search for my name. You'll find my web page, at the bottom of which there's my e-mail address.

Comment: I sent you an email

Comment: May i ask you if you receieved it?